# Music NowPlaying above TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I'm new in SwiftUI, I have an app that plays some audios from URLs in UIKit and I'm upgrading it to SwiftUI

I'm following this tutorial to have a bottom "now playing bar"
https://itnext.io/add-a-now-playing-bar-with-swiftui-to-your-app-d515b03f05e3

The problem is: my bar is below the tabView, but I want it above the tabView

[image: Text]

I don't know how to solve this. Maybe the tutorial is outdated because of an old SwiftUI version?

This is what I'm doing:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var playerOffset: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                VideosView()
                    .tabItem { Image(systemName: "film").accentColor(.black)
                        Text("Videos")}
                AudiosView()
                    .tabItem { Image(systemName: "headphones").accentColor(.black)
                        Text("Audios")}
            }
            NowPlayingBar(content: ListenNowView()).tag(0).tabItem { Label("Listen Now", systemImage: "play.circle.fill") }
        }
    }
}


struct Blur: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemChromeMaterial

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}

struct NowPlayingBar<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content

    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            //content
            ZStack {
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.0)).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 65).background(Blur())
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("cover").resizable().frame(width: 45, height: 45).shadow(radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3).padding(.leading)
                            Text("Shake It Off").padding(.leading, 10)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "play.fill").font(.title3)
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).padding(.horizontal)
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "forward.fill").font(.title3)
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).padding(.trailing, 30)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListenNowView: View {
    @State private var showMediaPlayer = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showMediaPlayer.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image("Cover").resizable().frame(width: 45, height: 45).shadow(radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3).padding(.leading)
                Text("Shake It Off").padding(.leading, 10)
                Spacer()
            }
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showMediaPlayer) {
        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your window group there is a mistake. The tutorial says "Now we only need to wrap our **individual views** in the NowPlayingBar(content: _) to prepare for this feature."

Doing this way will work :

```
TabView {
    NowPlayingBar(content: VideosView())
        .tabItem { Image(systemName: "film").accentColor(.black)
                        Text("Videos")}.tag(0)
    NowPlayingBar(content: AudiosView())
        .tabItem { Image(systemName: "headphones").accentColor(.black)
                        Text("Audios")}.tag(1)
                
    NowPlayingBar(content: ListenNowView())
        .tabItem { Label("Listen Now", systemImage: "play.circle.fill") }
        .tag(2)
}
```